# doublecsrf (import csrf-csrf ) invalid CSRF token Angular 15 et nodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, token, csrf

I am trying to make a POST request but I have an error ' invalid CSRF token '
I don't know where she got it from.
I tried to implement an HttpInterceptor to add the token in.
Here is the code for my interceptor class:

```
export class XsrfInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
   #headerName = 'x-xsrf-token';

   constructor(private tokenService: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) {
    }

    intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
     next: HttpHandler
   ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
   const token = this.tokenService.getToken();
  // Be careful not to overwrite an existing header of the same name.
     if (token !== null && !request.headers.has(this.#headerName)) {
         request = request.clone({
         headers: request.headers.set(this.#headerName, token)
 
    });
  }

  return next.handle(request);
}
```

}

then, I added the interceptor class as a provider to the app.module.
Here is my app.module.ts:

```
providers: [

{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: XsrfInterceptor,
  multi: true,
}
```

],

Then i added this lignes in imports:

```
  imports: [
BrowserModule,
HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
  cookieName: 'x-xsrf-token',
  headerName: 'x-xsrf-token'
}),
```

In the back (nodeJs), i added:

```
const {doubleCsrf} = require("csrf-csrf");


 const {generateToken,invalidCsrfTokenError, doubleCsrfProtection} =
  doubleCsrf({
    getSecret: () => "Secret",
    cookieName: "x-xsrf-token",
    cookieOptions: { sameSite: false, secure: false, signed: false },
});

module.exports = {
  doubleCsrfProtection: doubleCsrfProtection,
  generateToken: generateToken
}
```

In app.js :

```
 app.use(cookieParser("Secret"));
 app.use(doubleCsrfProtection);
```

and finally in auth.js, i added:

```
    function generateCsrfToken() {
    return uuidv4();
     }

    router.get("/csrf-token", rightsManager.requireSession(), function (req, res) {


   res.cookie("x-xsrf-token", generateCsrfToken());
   res.send({response: "ok"});
  res.status(200);
});
```

Thank you for any help.